# Sliding windows change size by inner items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change page sliding windows by its inner component maybe by CSS or JavaScript,
 but I don't know how to change size relative! Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Hmm could you please port some code? This would be CSS only, no JavaScript is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reference the inner component class or id and then set the width and height